# Underline under top nav, split with a downwards arrow

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hey I am trying to recreate this PSD (http://www.psdchat.com/resources/templates/freebie-hexal-portfolio-template/) in HTML CSS but need some help figuring out how to do the underline under the main menu.

So far I have:
     http://codepen.io/jasonm4130/pen/BKrwpE

```
nav.navbar.navbar-default
  .container-fluid
    .navbar-header
      button(type="button", class="navbar-toggle collapsed", data-toggle="collapse", data-target="#navbar-collapse-1", aria-expanded="false")
        span.sr-only Toggle Navigation
        span.icon-bar
        span.icon-bar
        span.icon-bar
      a(class="navbar-brand navbar-brand-hidden", href="#") Nikora's Photography
    #navbar-collapse-1.collapse.navbar-collapse
      ul.nav.navbar-nav
        li
          a(href="#") Portfolio
        li
          a(href="#") About
        li
          a(class="navbar-brand", href="#") Nikora's Photography
        li
          a(href="#") Blog
        li
          a(href="#") Get in Touch
.menu-underline-container
  .menu-underline
  .menu-underline-seperator
  .menu-underline
```

`//Header Custom Styles

```
.navbar.navbar-default
  background-color: #323232
  border: none
  border-radius: 0px
  &:after
   content: ""
   border-bottom: 2px solid

  .navbar-brand.navbar-brand-hidden
    color: #fff
    @media (min-width: 769px)
      display: none
  ul.nav.navbar-nav
    float: none
    display: inline-block

    li
      a
        color: white

    .navbar-brand
      margin: 0 auto
      text-align: center
      &:after
        content: ""
        width: 0
        border-top: 53px solid #323232
        border-left: 90px solid transparent
        border-right: 90px solid transparent
        position: absolute
        bottom: -53px
        left: 50%
        margin-left: -90px
      @media (max-width: 768px)
        display: none

  .navbar-collapse
    text-align: center

.menu-underline-container
  width: 90%
  margin: 1px auto
  .menu-underline
    display: inline-flex
    height: 1px
    width: auto
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e4e9eb
    @media (max-width: 1200px)
      width: 40%
  .menu-underline-seperator
    width: 52px
```

I am thinking that creating 3 divs inline and underneath with a border the same as my underline might work however I am pretty sure this is a really inefficient way of going about this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Please note I am using sass and jade.

Comment: did you try text-decoration: underline;

Comment: I'm to trying to underline the text but the entire menu, thanks though

Answer (score 0):

So my answer is add this

```
div#navbar-collapse-1:after //<--Check background, width, top, height with your PSD
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    background: #000;
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
    top: 10px;
```

And

```
.navbar.navbar-default ul.nav.navbar-nav .navbar-brand:after 
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    border-top: 53px solid #323232;
    border-left: 90px solid transparent;
    border-right: 90px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -53px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -90px;
    z-index: 2;//<---This
```

It's all added in compiled css

Comment: Thank you! I knew there must have been a better way to do it with after just wasn't sure.

Answer (score 0):

just if anyone else is trying to do this and needs the line to be split i also added to the .navbar-brand this makes a white triangle larger than the original black one and under it "separating" the underline.

```
&:before
    content: ""
    width: 0
    border-top: 64px solid #fff
    border-left: 110px solid transparent
    border-right: 110px solid transparent
    position: absolute
    bottom: -75px
    left: 50%
    margin-left: -110px
    z-index: 2
```

Thanks so much for the help!